# TwoWayView setAdaptor is not allowing to set the adaptor(HorizontalListView)

Tags: android

I tried using [TwoWayView](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view). My xml contains

```
<org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/rewardListView"
     style="@style/TwoWayView"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
     tools:context=".RewardActivity" />
```

I have created the `Adapter` which extends `RecyclerView.Adapter` and properly implemented every methods. Now in the activity, on the instance of `TwoWayView`, I try to set the adapter, but its not allowing me to set it up.

```
mRewardListView = (TwoWayView) findViewById(R.id.rewardListView);
adaptor = new RewardListViewAdaptor(mRewardList, this); 
mRewardListView.setAdapter(adaptor);
```

I am getting this error `"setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter) in TwoWayView cannot be cast to RewardListViewAdaptor"`.

Any help will be highly appreciated.